# How to import passwords to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The Google Chrome settings have the option to export passwords
I tried to search for import and could not find it
Is there a way to import passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "hidden" should be deleted and then the import will appear

```
<button id="menuImportPassword" class="dropdown-item" hidden="" role="menuitem">
        import
      </button>
```